# Get id of checked check boxes in a list on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid, scripting

I have a checkbox in each row. I have a button which deletes all the rows in which the check boxes are checked. For that, I have to get id of the rows where the checkbox is checked.I have written the following code. But not working. Pls help me out guys..

Button code :  `<a class="row-delete" align="left" onclick="deleteItem()"/>`

```
function deleteItem(){
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")){               
         $(":checkbox").change(function() {
            var notChecked = [], checked = [];
            $(":checkbox").map(function() {
               this.checked ? checked.push(this.id) : notChecked.push(this.id);
            });
            alert("checked: " + checked);
         });
         deleteAll(checked,0);
    }
}
```

What is wrong in above code?

Comment: checked = []; and this.checked may be confilicted

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with that code (other than your use of `.map` is incorrect), but you can just get `$(":checkbox:checked").get()` to get all checked boxes

Comment: $(":checkbox:checked").get().. Should I use in the place of $(":checkbox").map(function()??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering a `change` event handler in the `deleteItem` method that is not required, you need to just iterate through the checkboxes using .each() and update the required arrays

Also it is preferred to use `.each()` instead of `.map()` as you are not returning any value

```
function deleteItem(){
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")){               
        var notChecked = [], checked = [];
        $(":checkbox").each(function() {
            if(this.checked){
                checked.push(this.id);
            } else {
                notChecked.push(this.id);
            }
        });
        alert("checked: " + checked);
        deleteAll(checked,0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `onchange function` from `deleteItem` because when you `click` on `link` it will `re-init` on change of `checkbox elements`

```
function deleteItem(){
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")){               
         var notChecked = [], checked = [];
         $(":checkbox").each(function() {
            id=this.id;
            this.checked ? checked.push(id) : notChecked.push(id);
         });
         alert("checked: " + checked);
         deleteAll(checked,0);
    }
}
```

You can create an `array of checked checkboxes` like,

```
   $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        checked.push(this.id);
   });
```

**And** if you want to **delete items onclick of checkbox** then try like,

```
$(":checkbox").on('click',function() {
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
      alert($(this).attr('id'));// this item is ready to delete
   }
});
```

Comment: I need to delete from the Delete All button. I have to pass id's of row to deleteAll method..

Comment: Ok then don't use the `last one` method of my `answer`